# inject jquery and underscore to angular js component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, underscore.js

I am using angularjs, underscore and jQuery in my new service:

```
myModule.factory('MyService', ['MyResource', function (MyResource) {
     ....
    // Here I make use of _ and $
}]);
```

How can I inject underscore or jQuery to the new service so I can be sure that _ is underscore and $ is jquery?

I am looking for something like:

```
myModule.factory('MyService', [ 'underscore', 'jquery','MyResource', function (_, $, MyResource) {
     ....
    // Here I want to use $ and _ and be SURE that _ is underscore and $ is jquery
}]);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

based on @moderndegree's approach I have implemented the following code, I cannot say it is perfect but this way tester would know if it has jQuery dependency as `$window` is too generic object to inject.

```
'use strict';
(function () {
    var app= angular.module('app');
    //these are just references the instance of related lib so we can inject them to the controllers/services in an angular way.
    app.factory('jQuery', [
        '$window',
        function ($window) {
            return $window.jQuery;
        }
    ]);

    app.factory('Modernizr', [
        '$window',
        function ($window) {
            return $window.Modernizr;
        }
    ]);

    app.factory('Highcharts', [
    '$window',
    function ($window) {
        return $window.Highcharts;
    }
    ]);

})();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you include jQuery and Underscore in your HTML, they will be globally available. There is no need to "inject" them.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//documentcloud.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

If you wanted to include them in a module, you could do something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
service('vendorService', ['$q', '$timeout', '$window', function($q, $timeout, $window){
    var deferred = $q.defer(), libs = {};
    $script([
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js',
        '//documentcloud.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js'
    ], 'vendorBundle');
    $script.ready('vendorBundle', function() {
        libs.$ = $window.jQuery.noConflict();
        libs._ = $window._.noConflict();
        $timeout(function(){
            deferred.resolve(libs);
        }, 0);
    });
    this.getLibs = function(){
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}]).
controller('myController', ['$scope', 'vendorService', function($scope, vendorService){
    vendorService.getLibs().then(function(libs){
        $scope.jQueryVersion = libs.$.fn.jquery;
        $scope._ = libs._;
    });
}]);
```

Doing this will allow you to load the libraries asynchronously while keeping them from conflicting with previously loaded versions. There may be a better way to store references to the loaded libraries but this should work just fine.

Also, this example relies on a third party laoder ([$script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js)).

And here is a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/bzXGx/);

Comment: I don't think this answers the question of how to inject them. One may still want to inject them to, as OP says, "be sure" they are those values in that scope. Also to change them to be other things at some point in time by injecting something else. Also to get JShint/lint to stop complaining at you.

Comment: DerekR understood me correctly. What I I have another library that make use of _ or $? I am looking for a way to inject jquery and underscore.

Comment: Hopefully my revised answer helps. Let me know if you need me to adjust something.