# Undesrscore.js library is not working with Ionic based MobileFirst project

Tags: ionic-framework, underscore.js, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created hybrid application with mobilefirst using ionic. I have included underscore.js library in my project. When I try to access methods of underscore, I get errors like underscore is not defined

Comment: Its works perfectly fine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968297/use-underscore-inside-angular-controllers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408977/inject-jquery-and-underscore-to-angular-js-component

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have created an app using MobileFirst Studio - that is not the recommended path. The recommended path is to create a Cordova application using the MobileFirst CLI. You can then combine this with Ionic. This approach is more fool-proof.

You can follow these guides:

- https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/23/working-with-ibm-mobilefirst-and-the-ionic-framework/
- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/01/13/ionic-hybrid-mobile-app-using-mobilefirst-platform-7-1-cli/

Note that you did not mention the actual error you have received. Without this, the question is moot as there can be a number of possibilities. Please actually **mention the error you got**.

Comment: I have created project using CLI only and followed all references mentioned by you, Error is -  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortBy' of undefined